# Derivative of the log of normal

Tags: calculus

How can I find the derivative of μ in the next function?
$\log (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}  \exp{(\frac{-(x-μ)^2}{2σ^2 }}) )$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I fixed your formula. You can find the derivative as you usually would, treating everything but μ as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean "the derivative with respect to [tex]\mu[/tex]" rather than "the derivative of [tex]\mu[/tex]".

We can use the "laws of logarithms" to simplify that to $log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}\right)- \frac{(x- \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$.

The first term does not involve $\mu$ so its derivative is 0.  I presume that you know that the derivative of $(x- \mu)^2$, with respect to $\mu$, is $-2(x- \mu)$.